# What is the best way to detect external urls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

What is the best way to detect external urls in rails ?

```
def external?(url)
 return true if url is external
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no validation here or anything. This simply returns true if `url` includes the root_url

```
is_external_url?(url)
  true unless url.include?(root_url)
end
```

Comment: Conceptually, this a good idea. However, usually, `root_url` is pointing to something like `www.mydomain.com/index.html`. How would you handle that?

Comment: Hmmm root_url almost always points to the root URL of a site.

Another approach could be to add a string manually or yaml settings for different environments instead of the root_url above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_host_name(url)
  url = "http://#{url}" if URI.parse(url).scheme.nil?
  URI.parse(url).host.downcase
end

def is_external_url?(url)
  host = get_host_name(url)
  host != 'www.mydomain.com'
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you do not have access to current domain then check if the path is recognized in current application

```
def external?(url)
  !!(Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(URI.parse(url).path) rescue false)
end
```

Comment: This would return an incorrect result of the path of an external URL happens to match a path defined on your site.